# Custom filter with hook_filter_info() in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I got a problem when trying to create a custom filter with `hook_filter_info()`.
I have to make some replacement based on the fields of current viewed node. I am simply using the following code.

```
return str_replace('%people1%', 'REPLACING WORKING', $text);
```

In the process callback, that code works fine, but I can't get the current node ID (`menu_get_item()` or `arg()`). Also, I have to clear the cache every time I make some changes (`'cache' => FALSE`).

Is there anything I need to know about processing data in the process callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu_get_item()` and `arg()` don't return a different value when called from a process callback of a input filter; they are not returning the value you are expecting, probably because the input filter is called in a different context than you think.

An input filter is called when:

- A node body needs to be rendered
- A comment body needs to be rendered
- A entity field which is using a input format needs to be rendered
- A view created with the Views module is using an input format to render text entered from a user
- A module is using an input format to render text entered from a user

Even in the case the input filter is used to render the body of a node, there could still be two cases:

- The node is rendered alone in the page (e.g. http://example.com/node/2)
- The page shows more than one node (e.g. the front page that shows a list of nodes promoted to front page)

A module implementing an input filter cannot understand for which entity it is called, and the path of the current page doesn't necessarily give that information. For example, I could have a module that at mymodule/disclaimer shows the content of the node with ID equal to 2, or I could have a view that at example_path/just_to_make_an_example shows the excerpt taken from nodes matching some criteria I decided.

If you need to replace some words in a node body, for example replacing %author% with the username of the node creator, you should rather implement [hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.
I had a set of problems based on other custom modules.
A module that helped me is http://drupal.org/project/devel_if.
Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @CornelAndreev could you let me know how you handled your case, as I am facing similar issue?